# Reflection - how to get value at specified index of parameter

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to get the value of a specified index of a property using reflection.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937224/propertyinfo-getvalue-how-do-you-index-into-a-generic-parameter-using-reflec) works for standard properties that are of type List<> for example, but in my case, the collection I am trying to work with is of a different format:

```
public class NumberCollection : List<int>
{
    public NumberCollection()
    {
        nums = new List<int>();
        nums.Add(10);
    }

    public new int this[int i]
    {
        get { return (int) nums[i]; }
    }

    private List<int> nums;

}

public class TestClass
{
    public NumberCollection Values { get; private set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        Values = new NumberCollection();
        Values.Add(23);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();

        PropertyInfo pi1 = tc.GetType().GetProperty("Values");
        Object collection = pi1.GetValue(tc, null);

        // note that there's no checking here that the object really
        // is a collection and thus really has the attribute
        String indexerName = ((DefaultMemberAttribute)collection.GetType()
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultMemberAttribute),
                true)[0]).MemberName;
        // Code will ERROR on the next line...
        PropertyInfo pi2 = collection.GetType().GetProperty(indexerName);
        Object value = pi2.GetValue(collection, new Object[] { 0 });

        Console.Out.WriteLine("tc.Values[0]: " + value);
        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This code gives an AmbiguousMatchException ("Ambiguous match found."). I know my collection class is somewhat contrived, but can anyone help with this?

Comment: how is defined the indexer on NumberCollection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use

```
var prop = Type.GetProperties()
               .Where(prop => prop.DeclaringType == collection.GetType())
               .First();
```

Change `Collection.GetType()` to another type if you want. But basically: loop over the properties instead of using `Type.GetProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for all of the default members, you can ask for [Type.GetDefaultMembers()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getdefaultmembers.aspx), then examine the members to find the one that you are looking for.

Alternatively, if you know the data type of the indexer, you can call [GetPropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efekk662.aspx) with the type array specifier.