# Universal property path retriever for indexed/non-indexed properties

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

The aim is to write an universal property path retriever for indexed/non-indexed properties.
For indexing, only numerical indices have to be considered.

I have the following code. This supposed to retrieve properties based on a property path, even indexed properties.
I try to use it on MyObject, which has a Data property which is a `DataTable`.
The propertyPath would be e.g. Data.Rows[0]
When the execution reaches the line with the comment, a `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException` is thrown saying

> Parameter count mismatch.

```
    public static object GetPropertyPathValue(object value, string propertyPath)
    {
        object propValue = value;
        foreach (string propName in propertyPath.Split('.'))
        {
            string propName2 = propName;
            object[] index = null;
            int bracket1 = propName2.IndexOf("[");
            int bracket2 = propName2.IndexOf("]");
            if ((-1 < bracket1) && (-1 < bracket2))
            {
                index = new object[] { Int32.Parse(propName2.Substring(bracket1 + 1, bracket2 - bracket1 - 1)) };
                propName2 = propName2.Substring(0, bracket1);
            }
            PropertyInfo propInfo = propValue.GetType().GetProperty(propName2);
            propValue = propInfo.GetValue(propValue, index); // Exception thrown here
        }
        return propValue;
    }
```

I've checked this ([PropertyInfo.GetValue() - how do you index into a generic parameter using reflection in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937224/propertyinfo-getvalue-how-do-you-index-into-a-generic-parameter-using-reflec)) but could't find the answer to my question: **What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My open-source project [Xoml](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xoml/) has code which does exactly what you need. Take a look at [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/xoml/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Source/Xoml/Extensions/PropertyPathDescriptor.cs) particular source file.

Also - I think the reason you can't find the property is because default indexers called "Item". Look at line 116.

Comment: Nice. What exactly does your project do? I mean it uses XAML for what?

Comment: Thanks :) It doesn't use XAML, it reproduces the functionality of XAML in a thread-safe and efficient manner. I developed/used it for a heavily data-driven graphics rendering application.

Comment: Thank you. Line 116 of the linked source doesn't mention "Item"... Can you please give advice how can I achieve the needed functionality with the linked source?

Comment: Line 116 is the if condition to check if the property is indexed. Just under it, see the line `currentProperty = currentObject.GetType().GetProperty("Item");`